# Struct variables are not being saved correctly when printing linked list?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have a linked list and I am attempting to insert a new node, which seems to be successful at inserting the node where I want it to go, but the variables keep coming out as NULL. Could someone point to where I am causing this to happen?

Here is the print and insert method.

```
void printList(node *head)
{
    node *p;
    p = head;
    if(p->next == NULL)
            printf("No stops currently in the tour.");
    else
    {
            while(p->next != NULL)
            {
                    printf("Tour Stop: %s - Description: %s\n", p->name, p->name);
                    p = p->next;
                            }
    }
}


void insertInOrder(node *head, node *newNode)
{
    printf("What is the stop you want the new stop to come after? Type 'end' to insert at the end of the tour.");
    char key[100];
    scanf("%s", &key);
    getchar();

    node *p;
    p = head->next;
    if(head->next == NULL)
            head->next = newNode;

    else if(key == "end")
    {
            while(p->next != NULL)
                    p = p->next;

            p->next = newNode;
    printf("\nAT 57, newNode->info = %s and newNode->name = %s", newNode->info, newNode->name);
    }

    else
    {
            while(strcmp(p->name, key) != 0)
            {
                    if(p->next == NULL)
                    {
                            printf("Couldn't find the tour stop you requested, inserting at end of tour.");
                            break;
                    }

                    p = p->next;
            }

            p->next = newNode;
    }
```

And here is the createNewNode method I am using to pass into the insert method

```
node* createNewNode()
{
    node *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    printf("Enter the name of the new tour stop.\n");
    char newName[100];
    fgets(newName, sizeof(newName), stdin);
    newNode->name = newName;

    printf("Enter information about the tour stop. Max number of characters you can enter is 1000.\n");
    char newDescription[1000];
    newNode->info = newDescription;
    fgets(newDescription, sizeof(newDescription), stdin);
    return newNode;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not copying the string into the structure. You're just copying the pointer to a local variable inside `createNewNode()`:

```
char newName[100];
fgets(newName, sizeof(newName), stdin);
newNode->name = newName;
```

This means undefined behavior when you later access that stored pointer since it's no longer valid.

You need to have character space inside the structure, and copy (or just read) the string in there so it remains allocated for as long as the node exists.

Comment: "You need to have character space inside the structure", can you elaborate on this a little more? I follow what your saying elsewhere but this part throws me off. How else am I supposed to pass my information to my function without using a local variable node to store it?

Comment: @AKon it means you must allocate space for `name` to store a copy of the characters sequence. You can use strdup for that: `newNode->name = strdup(newName);`. Don't forget to `free(newNode->name);`, as well as the node itself, when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many issues with this code I don't even know where to start.

```
printf("What is the stop you want the new stop to come after? Type 'end' to insert at the end of the tour.");
char key[100];
scanf("%s", &key);
getchar();
```

If you absolutely need to use scanf (it's advised not to) to read the string you should add a maximum characters to read before the '%s' format specifier, like scanf("%99s", &key). You should read 99 characters instead of 100 so that null-termination won't overflow your array.

```
else if(key == "end")
{
    //code
}
```

Here instead of comparing the contents of key to the const char* "end" you simply compare the address of the array **key** to the address of const char* "end", you should use 
[strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) instead. (or even better [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/))

```
node* createNewNode()
{
    node *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    printf("Enter the name of the new tour stop.\n");
    char newName[100];
    fgets(newName, sizeof(newName), stdin);
    newNode->name = newName;

    printf("Enter information about the tour stop. Max number of characters you can enter is 1000.\n");
    char newDescription[1000];
    newNode->info = newDescription;
    fgets(newDescription, sizeof(newDescription), stdin);
    return newNode;
}
```

Here the new node's name and info pointers will point to memory that has been released after the call to **createNewNode** has returned. This is undefined behaviour and your program may segfault or worse.

You should copy the read buffers to new ones allocated on the heap and set your pointers to point at them, or allocate the buffers on the heap at the first place.

```
int newDescriptionLength = strlen(newDescription) + 1; //plus 1 for null termination
char* newDescriptionCopy = malloc(newDescriptionLength);
strncpy(newDescriptionCopy, newDescription, newDescriptionLength);
newNode->info = newDescriptionCopy;
```

[strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) will make sure that your newDescriptionCopy string is null-terminated after
all characters of the source string newDescription have been copied.

The allocated buffers should be taken into account when freeing a node.

Also, you should read one character less with fgets too, because supplying the exact count
of characters allowed won't null terminate your string.

You should resolve those issues before delving deeper at your problem because your program is full of undefined behavior and it won't be safe to make assumptions during debugging.

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you! I read unwind's answer and knew what he meant but it didn't really click until you mentioned allocating on the heap vs the stack. Makes much more sense now. Pardon the other errors, I (obviously) have not been coding in C for very long so I'm just trying to get major functions to work before looking at the little things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see of your code (you have not printed the calling functions or init of the linked list, if there is one), it looks like you are never checking the first element (i.e. head). So when the list is completeley empty then head will point to NULL. So using your print function as an example you should have:

```
void printList(node *head)
{
    node *p;
    p = head;

    // Check if the list contains anything
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Tour Stop: %s - Description: %s\n", p->name, p->name); // print first/head element

        // Continue while there are more elements
        while(p->next != NULL)
        {
            printf("Tour Stop: %s - Description: %s\n", p->name, p->name);
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

It may be the same for your insert function, so that you never insert anything?

**Note**: Unwind also has a very valid point in his answer